# drop all rows in 2 columns if value in one column is beyond a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, twitter

I have two columns "sentiment" and "tweets".
Sentiment contains numbers, tweets strings.
I have a dataframe df with these two columns. And now I would like to drop all rows in which tweet length is beyond 150 letters.

I am able to drop the values in X via:

```
    X = df["x"]
    X =[x for x in X if len(x)<151]
```

But this leaves the y values untouched.

How to drop both x and y values (=the whole row) if x is beyond 150 in length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html#pandas.Series.str.len):

```
X = df[df['x'].str.len() <= 150]
```

as a [boolean mask](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to remove those rows where the tweets exceeds the limit

Example:

```
In[66]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentiment':np.arange(5), 'tweets':['asdas','a','asdasdas','asdasdasdas','asdasdasdas']})
df

Out[66]: 
   sentiment       tweets
0          0        asdas
1          1            a
2          2     asdasdas
3          3  asdasdasdas
4          4  asdasdasdas

In[67]:
X = df[df['tweets'].str.len() <=5]
X

Out[67]: 
   sentiment tweets
0          0  asdas
1          1      a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the two lists together into a third list, so it'd be a list of two-tuples.

```
>>>x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>y = [9, 8, 7, 6]
>>>z = zip(x, y)
>>>z
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6)]
```

With the zipped list, you could do a similar list comprehension

```
X = df["x"]  # tweets
Y = df["y"]  # sentiments
Z = zip(x, y)
Z = [z for z in Z if len(z[0]) < 151]
```

To unzip the lists again, you'd have to do something along the lines of

```
X = []
Y = []
for z in Z:
    X.append(z[0])
    Y.append(z[1])
```